# Running a SH Script in PHP Exec via Bitbucket Webhook Throwing Error

Tags: php, shell, bitbucket, exec, bundle

I have a `deploy.sh` script that when run manually in the folder it lives in, will run fine.

If I run the script from within' the folder on the server, it works fine.

It is failing when I am using Webhooks on Bitbucket - when it's calling the script, it's throwing an error.

```
./deploy.sh: line 24: bundle: command not found
```

The PHP code is

```
<?php

exec('cd /to/my/path && ./deploy.sh 2>&1', $output);
print_r($output);
```

line 24 on the script is

```
bundle exec middleman build --clean
```

I can't work out why this is failing when called by the external service but works fine on the server. The user is the same as on the server and the paths are correct.

Can anyone see where I might be going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Try the full path to `bundle`. When executed via PHP, it may not be in the path

Comment: Did try that, it gives more path errors for the other commands. I think `exec` is running as a different user, that doesn't have ruby installed? Is that a possibility?

Comment: It's more likely just the PATH variable that isn't set properly. Try this: from an SSH session, type `echo $PATH`. Then from PHP, call `exec('echo $PATH', $output); print_r($output);`. How different are they?